# Wait for all the subprocess to be completed and then execute the next line

Tags: python

```
for command in commands:
   process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
   processes.append(process)
   time.sleep(3)
for process in processes:
   process.wait()

_nextLine() #Should be executed after all the processes are completed
```

I want Python to execute _nextLine(), only after my processes are complete. I have written the above snippet, but it is not working as expected. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why you sleep between spawning processes?

Comment: That's there for some other purpose. A few files will be created as soon as the command executes, and I've to capture them before running another command.